# Can't Install Jedi -Autocomplete in Sublime Text 3

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, python-3.6, jedi

I'm trying to install the jedi autocomplete package in Sublime Text 3. Each time I try to install it using Package Control it just doesn't complete installation even after several HOURS!!!

It shows me no error messages . The package just doesn't install .

I've installed Various Packages but never faced this issue.It just Keeps displaying at the bottom of the Sublime Text as Installing but never completes the installation.

How to solve this problem?
Is there any other way to install the package?

Comment: Is a more accurate error message available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. Reinstalling sublime and rebooting my Windows 10 seems to have fixe this issue.

I tried to install jedi again, but in vain. So I reinstalled Sublime Text 3, rebooted my Windows 10 and I was able to install the jedi Autocomplete package.